# Getting results based on two unique fields (same as SQL DISTINCT) in searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a `Follow` model which has (among others) two attributes `follower_id` and `followable_id`.

This is the search_data definition:

```
{
  name: [followable.name, follower.name],
  username: [followable.username, follower.username],
  followable_id: followable_id,
  follower_id: follower_id
}
```

I want to perform a search that returns unique results considering the fields [followable_id, follower_id]. I think this is similar to `SELECT DISTINCT ON followable_id, follower_id FROM "follows"`.

For example, `[[10, 2], [2, 5], [2, 10]]` should return `[[10, 2], [2, 5]]` or `[[2, 5], [2, 10]]`, for me it makes no difference the order. For me it only matters that the pair does not repeat.

This is how my current search looks like:

```
search = Follow.search('*',
  fields: [:name, :username],
  match: :word_start,
  misspellings: {below: 5},
  page: params[:page],
  per_page: 10,
  where: {_or: [
    {follower_id: current_user.id}, 
    {followable_id: current_user.id}
  ]}
)
```

**Edit:**

I thought DISTINCT could be similar. However, I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (follower_id, followable_id) follower_id, followable_id FROM "follows";

 follower_id | followable_id 
-------------+---------------
          27 |            35
          28 |            12
          33 |            27
          35 |            27
```

In this example, it should not return `[27, 35]` or `[35, 27]`. But as you can see, the query did return the repeated pair.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about searchkick but I can share the E.S equivalent (if it helps) and you can convert it into searchKick equivalent.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['follower_id'] + '|' + doc['followable_id']"
        },
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahil, what do you use the size key for?

Comment: size at the root level is for query results and size with-in aggregation is for aggregation results. If this solve your problem, please do accept the answer & upvote. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I get empty results, here is the json I am sending to ES: '{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":[{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"follower_id":2}}]}},{"bool":{"filter":[{"term":{"followable_id":2}}]}}]}}]}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false,"size":0,"aggs":{"distinct":{"terms":{"script":{"source":"doc['follower_id'] + '|' + doc['followable_id']"},"size":100}}}}'

Comment: Here is an example document: {"_index":"follows_staging_20200828101649804","_type":"_doc","_id":"1","_version":1,"_seq_no":0,"_primary_term":1,"found":true,"_source":{"name":["user1","user2"],"username":["myuser1","myuser2"],"followable_id":1,"follower_id":2}}